# Append sqlite3 data from csv to a table whose 1 column is - id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

So I have a table, which has the first column called id as autoincrement.

Now, Suppose I have data in the table with ids- 1,2,3

And I also have some data in the csv that starts with id 1,2,3

This is the code that I am trying to use-

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sub_features (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,featureId INTEGER, name TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(featureId) REFERENCES features(id))")
df = pd.read_csv(csv_location+'/sub_features_table.csv')
df.to_sql("sub_features", con, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I am getting this error-

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: sub_features.id
```

How do I make sure that data gets appended and the id gets set as per requirement and in case the entire row is a duplicate then it gets ignored?

To explain further, Say I have  a table:

```
id   |   Name
1    |   Abhisek
2    |   Amit
```

And I am trying to import this csv to the same table:

```
id   |   Name
1    |   Abhisek
2    |   Rahul
```

Then my resultant table should be:

```
id   |   Name
1    |   Abhisek
2    |   Amit
3    |   Rahul
```

Comment: do you want to update existing rows or skip new ones from csv?

Comment: skip if the entire row is an exact match, else append to existing table.

Comment: what does *exact match* mean? do `(1, Amit)` in database and `(1, Abhisek)` in csv form an exact match?

Comment: 1    |   Abhisek  and 1    |   Abhisek  is an exact match.

Comment: and what should we do in case of non-exact match with same id?

Comment: Append it with id+1 as shown in example.